# How do I access my software updater if it doesn't display anywhere?

Tags: boot, system-installation, updates, software-installation

I'm really struggling to update my ubuntu os... I've got three different versions of it on my pc namely Blackbox, twm & Kde/ kubuntu. However I can't access my software updater from any of them neither will my normal auto updates show.

Any suggestions please

Comment: i had this same issue. try typing `sudo software-properties-gtk` into terminal
EDIT: `sudo software-center`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get the GUI to work for you, terminal is also great and easy to use:
The basics:
Upgrading your entire system:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Installing new software:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

Upgrading to a new release:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Of course, if you are root(`whoami`), you can drop the sudo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running unity, you should be able to find it in the dash:
click on the ubuntu button on the top left and then type 'Software Updater'.
Otherwise you can run it from a terminal (commandline): `update-manager`

What version of ubuntu are you running 12.04?